# Running AspectJ compiler in Tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, compiler-construction, aspectj

I wanna use the AOP(aspect oriented programming) while running tomcat.
I don't want using spring aop.
so I search for the way how the aspectj works. 
finally, I found the way which is posted on eclipse [forum](http://dev.eclipse.org/mhonarc/lists/aspectj-users/msg02294.html).

I downloaded aspectj component at the eclipse hompage. next, I copy three libraries, 'aspectjrt.jar' 'aspectjtools.jar', 'aspectjweaver', and paste to tomcat's lib folder.

After all, I edited web.xml. adding following code at the jsp servlet part.

```
    <init-param>
        <param-name>compiler</param-name>
        <param-value>org.aspectj.tools.ant.taskdefs.Ajc11CompilerAdapter</param-value>
    </init-param>
```

I think this adding code will be run when loading jsp pages for using ajc.

Next, Command line set up of variables, I add next code at 'catalina.bat'.

```
   Set CATALINA_OPTS=-Dorg.aspectj.tools.ant.taskdefs.AjcTask.COMMAND_EDITOR=ajee.adapters.AutoAspectpathRewriter
```

Finally, I make the aspect code contained pointcut and advices, and move it tomcat lib folder.
As a result, aspect code did not execute.

while writing the aspect code, I tested it and confirmed working it. 
maybe, it isn't caused by aspect code.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow, your post will not be taken seriously until you fix your grammar mistakes.